# Change colour only during mouse click event

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS shape that acts as a stop button for some audio:

```
.double-border {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;

  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.double-border:before {
  background: black;

  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  right: 7px;
  bottom: 7px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

When the button is clicked it changes colour during the click, and returns to the original colour when the click is released.

I've achieved this by creating two functions to chnage the colour:

```
function toggleStop(param) {

param.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #C8C8C8;");

}

function toggleStart(param) {

param.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #f1f1f1;");

}
```

One function is for an onmousedown event and one for an onmouseup event.

```
<div class="double-border" onclick="stop();" onmousedown="toggleStop(this);" onmouseup="toggleStart(this);">
```

This kind of works, except if the user hold down the click and simultaneously moves the mouse pointer off the button. In this scenario the button remains the onmousedown colour which I don't want.

Is there a better way of achieving this without too much additional code?

Comment: consider mousleave, mouseenter also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this with pure css?

```
.double-border:active,.double-border:focus {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```css
.double-border {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;

  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.double-border:before {
  background: black;

  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  right: 7px;
  bottom: 7px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.double-border:active,.double-border:focus {
background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="double-border" onclick="stop();"></div>
```